# How to use Two-Way Data Binding to pass data from child to parent component?

Tags: angularjs, angular, data-binding, components

I'm trying to pass a boolean from my modal component to my main component but it 's not working.

My modal (child) :

```
export class ModalForm implements OnChanges{
    @Input() isVisible;
    @Output() visibleChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
    constructor() {
        this.isVisible = false;
     }
    save() {
          this.isVisible = false;
          this.visibleChange.emit(this.isVisible);
        });
    }
}
```

My Main Component :

```
<section [class.modalOpen]="isModalFormVisible>
   <modal-form [(isVisible)]="isModalFormVisible"></modal-form>
</section>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For shorthand two-way binding to work the names of the input and output need to match where the output has an addditional `Change` suffix

```
@Input() isVisible;
@Output() isVisibleChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

Then you can use it like

```
<modal-form [(isVisible)]="isModalFormVisible"></modal-form>
```

With your code you would need the long form:

```
<modal-form [isVisible]="isModalFormVisible" (visibleChange)="isModalFormVisible = $event"></modal-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main component

```
<section [class.modalOpen]="isModalFormVisible>
   <modal-form (visibleChange)="modalVisibleChanged($event)"></modal-form>
</section>
```

your main.component.ts

```
modalVisibleChanged(event){
    this.isModalFormVisible = event;
}
```